# How to provide dynamic usage of select query in SQL Server 2008 based on a variable value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `myTable` with these columns and sample data:

```
Id     Name  Period0Status Period1Status Period2Status
-------------------------------------------------------
1      Mark      1             2             3
2      John      2             3             3
3      Brad      1             1             1
4      John      3             3             3
5      Mark      1             3             2
etc...
```

What I want is to use those data but the column names should be taken according to a SQL variable. What I need is something like that:

```
declare @0_period varchar(50) = 'Period_0'
declare @1_period varchar(50) = 'Period_1'
declare @2_period varchar(50) = 'Period_2'

declare @counter = 0;

while @counter < 3
begin
   insert into #Results(Period, JohnVolume, MarkVolume, JoshVolume)
       select 
           '@' + @counter + '_period',
           sum(case when(name = 'John' and (Period+@counter+Status = 3) then 1 else 0)),
           sum(case when(name = 'Mark' and (Period+@counter+Status = 3) then 1 else 0)),
           sum(case when(name = 'Brad' and (Period+@counter+Status = 3) then 1 else 0))
       from 
           myTable

   set @counter = @counter + 1
end
```

I could not find the correct syntax to provide the dynamic query here. Any help would be appreciated. SQL Server 2008 is used.

Output table I want to produce be like:

```
Period    JohnVolume  MarkVolume  BradVolume
Period_0      1            0          0
Period_1      2            1          0
Period_2      2            1          0
```

It should basically counts the amount of 3s for each (John,Mark and Brad) for each period. I gotta find out how to correct the syntax for the parts that @counter is used inside the select query.

Comment: Looks like `PIVOT` to me.

Comment: Technically an unpivot followed by a pivot, actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how you could do this, with a cross apply to derive the values for each period and a count(case...) for the end values:

```
SELECT period
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN Name = 'John' AND val = 3 THEN 1 END) [JohnVolume]
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN Name = 'Mark' AND val = 3 THEN 1 END) [MarkVolume]
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN Name = 'Brad' AND val = 3 THEN 1 END) [BradVolume]
FROM myTable
CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('Period_0', Period0Status), ('Period_1', Period1Status), ('Period_2', Period2Status)) unp(period, val)
GROUP BY period
```

The cross apply works as an unpivot to get each period status and the values within them, and the conditional case statements work as a pivot.

Alternatively, you could use an actual UNPIVOT/PIVOT if you want. An example would be:

```
SELECT Period, John JohnVolume, Mark MarkVolume, Brad BradVolume
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM myTable
    UNPIVOT (val FOR period IN (Period0Status, Period1Status, Period2Status)) U
    WHERE val = 3) T
PIVOT (COUNT(val) FOR Name IN ([John], [Mark], [Brad])) P
```

Comment: Plus1  Well done!  Head and shoulders over my initial thinking.